# Is verbatimbox.sty missing in frozen TeX Live 2012?

Tags: packages, texlive

I found that `verbatimbox.sty` is not directly available in the now frozen `TeX Live 2012`. Having a `\usepackage{verbatimbox}` generates a **`verbatimbox.sty` not found** message on compilation. I can see that there is only a `verbatimbox-r15878.tar.xz` in the location `c:\texlive\2012\tlpkg\backups` on a Windows machine.

In contrast, the package `verbatimbox` is in its decompressed form and `verbatimbox.sty` is available in the fresh distribution from a TeX Live 2012 ISO from TUG (from last year).

Anyone else who has noticed this? Any work around?

It doesn't seem that the package maintainer `Steven B. Segletes` has a contact email address.

Comment: As such it's [available on MiKTeX only](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verbatimbox) due to license(may be), nevertheless place it a folder [respecting TeX directory structure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/15717) to make it available to all `.tex` files or otherwise [place in same working folder](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/verbatimbox/verbatimbox.sty).

Comment: Looking at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatimbox, I'd say it was removed for license reasons.

Comment: @JosephWright The author is quite active on this site can you ping steven-b-segletes ? I suspect it is just an oversight that no licence is included.

Comment: I was unaware of a problem @JosephWright. I have uploaded V2.01 today to CTAN with an LPPL license prominantly displayed. Not sure how this works its way in TeX Live.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes. Thanks. I think then I can download the latest version and place it in the TexLive 2012 directory. I have to check from the distribution from the last year iso release of TeXLive how to properly place the files belonging to verbatimbox. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the [CTAN-page of the package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatimbox) the `verbatimbox` package has an

> Un­known Sta­tus, No In­for­ma­tion Avail­able

as for license information. TeX Live is removing all these packages from their repositories to provide a bundle with only software licensed under free licenses. This is necessary to make Linux distributions like Debian that have a quite restrictive license policy to include TeX Live into their repositories.

The package is auto-removed by the update mechanism of TeX Live, so it will be in the `backup` directory of TeX Live. The ISO-image was produced before the removal so the package is included. To use it, copy it from `backup` into you `texmf-local` or `~/.texmf` directory, or download it from CTAN.

**Edit:** Due to the comments below by @texenthusiast, I found out that in Windows it is possible to restore packages from backup in the TeX Live Manager GUI with an option in the `Actions` menu. The same should be possible also by the command line `tlmgr` tool (see documentation).

Comment: on Windows is restore backup style possible ? as OP is on Win

Comment: Thanks. I do also have the first iso release of TexLive 2012 installed in parallel with the frozen TexLive 2012. Perhaps I can just copy the appropriate files from the first iso release and place it in the frozen distribution and afterwards refresh the new distribution database. 1 vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan This should work as expected. Mention to run `mktexlsr` after copying the files to make them available.

Comment: @texenthusiast In TeX Live Manager GUI there is an option in the `Actions` menu bar to restore the backup packages. This should work. I have just a plain installation for tests in an Windows VM, where nothing is in backup, so I can't test it for you :(

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk Thanks you may absorb the comments inside answer with * Windows Users are welcome to test and add here.

Comment: @texenthusiast Improved the answer to tell readers of the answer directly where to find the option.

Comment: @yCalleecharan Under Linux `texhash` is just a symlink to `mktexlsr`. AFAIK `texhash` is just another popular name, so both are provided for the same functionality. If I'm wrong, please correct me…